# Sort according to all fields in the list

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, comparator, comparable

```java
import java.util.Date;

public class Emp {
    public Emp() {
    }

    private int Id;
    private String name;
    private Date date_of_join;
    private String city;
    private int age;
    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Date getDate_of_join() {
        return date_of_join;
    }
    public void setDate_of_join(Date date_of_join) {
        this.date_of_join = date_of_join;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

I have a bean with 5 fields. I want to sort all the five field according to 1 than 2 than 3rd than 4 and than 5

It consists of

String
String,
Date,
String , 
Int.

What could i do to sort the `list<Emp>` inside the list according to id, name, date of join, city, age

Comment: `Comparator.comparing(YourObject::getFirstString).thenComparing(YourObject::getSecondString)....`

Comment: @Eugene is there any inbuild method of Collections api for that as i am using   Comparator<Emp> compareById = (Emp o1, Emp o2) -> o1.getId().compareTo( o2.getId() );
         
         
         Collections.sort(Emp, compareById);

Comment: @Eugene above code only sort the id .

Comment: `Collections.sort(employees, Comparator.comparing.....)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a custom `Comparator`:

```
myList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Emp::getId)
                      .thenComparing(Emp::getName)
                      .thenComparing(Emp::getDate_of_join)
                      .thenComparing(Emp::getCity)
                      .thenComparingInt(Emp::getAge));
```

**EDIT:**
To address the requirement in the comments, you could sort the items accoring to the length of the city's string before sorting by it:

```
myList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Emp::getId)
                      .thenComparing(Emp::getName)
                      .thenComparing(Emp::getDate_of_join)
                      .thenComparingInt(e -> e.getCity().length())
                      .thenComparing(Emp::getCity)
                      .thenComparingInt(Emp::getAge));
```

Comment: @dhS care to elaborate?

Comment: please check the updated pojo which need to sort .. I have the List<Emp> which i need to sort according to each field

Comment: Might just be `.thenComparing(Emp::getDate_of_join)`

Comment: @Mureinik  thanks let me know one thing more if i need the city in some specific order what can i do for it

Comment: @dhS what specific order?

Comment: @Mureinik Only the city field by length of the string and else are by normal sorting